# Meaning of the phrase "deceive the truth"

Tags: poetry

So I'm reading this poem, Milton's "How Soon Hath Time" and doing a line-by-line analysis. But I'm stuck in this line where the poet says "Perhaps my semblance might deceive the truth". Can anybody help me find the meaning of this line? Does "deceive the truth" mean the same as "betray the truth"?
https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44744/sonnet-7-how-soon-hath-time-the-subtle-thief-of-youth

Comment: “Deceive the truth” in the sense of appearing  different from what it really is. Milton is saying that his aspect may look different from what it really is. Reading on,  *he is saying  that  his aspect may look  more mature   than he really is as a person.*

Comment: It's anthromorphic; the truth would have to be seen as a person in juxtaposition to his "semblance" (appearance). He is inverting what logically would be: the truth cannot be found in my appearance. It's a poetic device, and I can't be bothered to go and find all the weird ones so I can give this inversion a Greek name. I am sure there is one. Perhaps some luminary will tell us....

Comment: I thought poetic interpretation was off-limits...

Answer (score 0):

**“Deceive the truth”**

a form of **self-deception:**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/self-deception) idiom

> The act of deceiving oneself or the state of being deceived by
>   oneself.

Milton admits that his view may look different from what is
 reality .

Comment: I suggest "self-deception" is very far from Milton's meaning and who is deceived is rather the reader or, in the text, the observer.